# Difficulty in simplifying the boolean expression:(X+Y)(X+Y’)(X’+Z)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra, boolean

While simplifying the above boolean expression. I have found to be using 2 methods yielding 2 different results.

A) By multiplying brackets only

A: $(x+y)(x+7)(\bar{x}+2)$
Since $\mathrm{XX}=\mathrm{X}$ ( By Idempotent Law) and $Y \bar{Y}=0$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\text { L.H.S. } & =(X+X \bar{Y}+Y X+0)(\bar{X}+Z) \\
& =(X+X \bar{Y}+Y X)(\bar{X}+Z) \\
& =(X \bar{X}+X Z+X \bar{Y} \bar{X}+X \bar{Y} Z+Y X \bar{X}+Y X Z) \quad \text { (Distribution Law) } \\
& =(X \bar{X}+X Z+X \bar{X} \bar{Y}+X \bar{Y} Z+Y X \bar{X}+X Y Z) \quad \text { ( Commutative Law) }
\end{aligned}
$$
Since $X \bar{X}=0$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\text { L.H.S. } & =(0+X Z+0 \bar{Y}+X \bar{Y} Z+Y 0+X Y Z) \\
& =(X Z+X \bar{Y} Z+X Y Z) \\
& =(X Z+X Z(Y+\bar{Y}))
\end{aligned}
$$

B) By multiplying brackets and simplifying 1st bracket inside:

$\begin{aligned} & \text { Q-9 }(x+y)(x+\bar{y})(\bar{x}+z) \\ & \rightarrow(x \cdot x+x \bar{y}+y x+y \bar{y})(\bar{x}+z) \\ & \rightarrow(x \cdot x = x) \rightarrow \text { Idempotent low } \\ &(x \cdot \bar{x} = 0) \rightarrow \text { Complement } \\ & \rightarrow(x+x \bar{y}+y x+0)(\bar{x}+z) \\ & \Rightarrow(x(\bar{y}+y)+x)(\bar{x}+z) \\ & \Rightarrow(x(1)+x)(\bar{x}+z)[\bar{y}+y=y] \\ & \rightarrow(x)(\bar{x}+z) \\ & \rightarrow x \bar{x}+x z \\ & \rightarrow 1+x z\end{aligned}$

Comment: Answer is $xz$. You made a mistake at last.

Comment: In part A or B ? @Hypernova

Comment: @Hypernova I have edited a few mistakes.

Comment: The first is not done.  Note $Y+\overline Y=1$  The second is wrong at the last line because $x\overline x=0$ and $1+anything$ would be $1$

Comment: Also, the $7$ and $2$ look like OCR errors.